# Compare with previous value and merge results

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Please consider me a novice in pandas.

I have a dataframe as below

```
        id      refseqno        xml
0   28893323        2       <my_xml>...</my_xml>
1   29057856        6       <my_xml>...</my_xml>
2   29417872        18      <my_xml>...</my_xml>
3   30081656        58      <my_xml>...</my_xml>
4   34470834        6       <my_xml>...</my_xml>
5   35025043        19      <my_xml>...</my_xml>
6   35025043        45      <my_xml>...</my_xml>
7   35025043        7       <my_xml>...</my_xml>
8   37761341        13      <my_xml>...</my_xml>
9   42458085        23      <my_xml>...</my_xml>
```

I want to compare current `id` value with previous `id` value. If they are same then I need to get all `refseqno's` and in a single row, so that there is single row for same id but that row should have all `refseqno's`

```
        id      refseqno        xml
0   28893323        2           <my_xml>...</my_xml>
1   29057856        6           <my_xml>...</my_xml>
2   29417872        18          <my_xml>...</my_xml>
3   30081656        58          <my_xml>...</my_xml>
4   34470834        6           <my_xml>...</my_xml>
5   35025043        7,19,45     <my_xml>...</my_xml>
6   37761341        13          <my_xml>...</my_xml>
7   42458085        23          <my_xml>...</my_xml>
```

Below is the code that I have where I am able to get True or False if the previous `id` value but am unable to proceed further.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv", encoding='utf-8')
df.columns = ['id', 'refseqno', 'xml']
df_tmp['id'] = df['id'].shift(1)
df['valid'] = (df['id'] == df_tmp['id'])
df
```

Comment: this should work `df.groupby('id')['refseqno'].agg(','.join)` try it.

Comment: This works, Thank you. But how can I get output such that it has 3 columns namely id, refseqno and xml where refseqno contains seqno's

Comment: I have added my answer please refer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join `refseqno` using groupby and `agg` function then assign to refseqno after removing duplicates from `df`

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates('id').assign(refseqno=df.astype(str).groupby('id')['refse
qno'].agg(','.join).values)

         id refseqno                   xml
0  28893323        2  <my_xml>...</my_xml>
1  29057856        6  <my_xml>...</my_xml>
2  29417872       18  <my_xml>...</my_xml>
3  30081656       58  <my_xml>...</my_xml>
4  34470834        6  <my_xml>...</my_xml>
5  35025043  19,45,7  <my_xml>...</my_xml>
8  37761341       13  <my_xml>...</my_xml>
9  42458085       23  <my_xml>...</my_xml>
```